# Is this passive or potential form?

Tags: translation

I’m having a hard time figuring out whether this is passive or potential or both (if that’s possible)?
And how would you literally translate it?
Here’s my attempt: As for in this essay, many mistakes of grammar can be seen.

この作文には文法の間違いがたくさん見られる。

Answer (score 5):

Technically it is passive.

Such kind of passive form that takes inanimate subjects, 非情の受け身(inanimate passive form), is considered an exceptional part of Japanese grammar.
(Usually passive forms in Japanese can only take animate subjects.)

It is worth noting that according to [Daijisen](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-656590), the inanimate passive form was initially imported to Japanese from Western languages after the Meiji era.

So there is the possibility that the use of 見られる (is seen) in question:

> この作文には文法の間違いがたくさん見られる。

is actually derived from the English phrase "can be seen".

Please refer to this material for further information (it is written in Japanese though)

http://repository.tufs.ac.jp/bitstream/10108/57715/1/isre013001.pdf

Comment: Excellent! As for 非情の受身, I found articles here (http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/passive/passive-8/) and here (http://nihongonosensei.net/?p=4324). They are easier to be read though they are also written in Japanese.

Comment: Why did you use "can be seen" rather than simple "is seen/found"? Isn't this 見られる purely passive?

Answer (score 1):

> この作文には文法の間違いがたくさん見られる。

質問者は、「見られる」という表現の語尾の形から、passive form（【文法】受身、受動態）、
あるいは、potential form:【文法】可能形のいずれであるかを質問していることは明白です。

実際の日本語を使う立場で考えると、「この作文には文法の間違いがたくさん見られる。」という表現は良く使われます。そして、その意味は、「この作文には文法の間違いがたくさんある *There are many grammatical mistakes in this composition.*」という意味に過ぎません。すなわち、「見られる」という表現を使っていますが、この表現を使った人は、「ある」という意味を丁寧に表現しているに過ぎず、文法的に「受身」であるか、あるいは「可能形」であるかを全く意識していないと思われます。

質問者を含めて日本語を勉強している人が、「見られる」という表現を見て、passive formかpotential formのいずれであるかを特定したい気持ちはよくわかりますが、この表現は、いずれでもなく、単に、「間違いがたくさんある」という意味で使われていると理解することが生きた日本語を学ぶ上で大切な見方だと思います。